# Angular 14 routes any route that is below parameters route (i.e. :id) are not able to route

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

My app-routing.module.ts contains parameter routes that lead to a distinct id. I found out that my wildcard path was broken while testing my routes.

After considerable testing, it turns out that using a different route below the parameter path also doesn't work.

app-routing.module.ts (original setup)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/about/about.module').then((m) => m.AboutModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/contact/contact.module').then((m) => m.ContactModule),
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/profile/profile.module').then(
        (m) => m.ProfileModule
      ),
  },
   // PATH BELOW NOT WORKING 
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts (testing by swapping some path setup)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/profile/profile.module').then(
        (m) => m.ProfileModule
      ),
  },
   // PATH BELOW NOT WORKING 
  {
    path: 'about',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/about/about.module').then((m) => m.AboutModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/contact/contact.module').then((m) => m.ContactModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: The id path Parma is not limited to number. It will match anything that does not contain an /. If you want to match only a number use matcher with custom logic. But I would advise to use prefix like `profile/:profileID`

Comment: @Akxe I tried using a matcher but have difficulties with child routes. But why is it a bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a `redirectTo` route must contain a `pathMatch` property, otherwise it will not route (it should not even compile)

Next, it's a bad practice to provide routes at the same level like so

```
/home/about
/home/contact
/home/:id
```

Technically, it works, but because it relies on the order of the provided routes. if your `:id` route is set first in the list, then `about` and `contact` become ids too.

So the best solution would be to just separate the routes like so

```
/home/about
/home/contact
/home/items/:id
```

Otherwise, you can use the `canMatch` guard (like `canActivate`), but again, I would consider this a bad practice. Just follow a RESTFul-like structure for your routes, that's the best and simplest option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! But how would you create something like website with a personalized slug URL i.e. Instagram.com/foo.

Comment: @syahiruddin I would do `instagram.com/users/foo`

Comment: I've read the Angular documentation on routing-with-urlmatcher https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher is it safe to say that if I want to set the username/id as the path, I can use a urlmatcher?

Comment: I would rather use the canMatch guard but up to you !

Comment: Sorry just one last thing, to get a better grasp of this. You mentioned that is a bad practice, if you may elaborate on why it is a bad practice or direct me to an article about this so that I can learn? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any, since this is only a personal opinion. But the reasoning is as follows : if you rely on an array order (which is highly unstable) for something to work the way you want it, then i'ts probably not something you wish to do. If someone comes in, do not know that, and adds a new element in the array at the wrong place, he breaks the whole application.

Comment: I see! it makes perfect sense from a reusability and scalability stand point. Take your time!